# ASP.NET MVC EF Null foreign key in database - but why?

Tags: asp.net-mvc, entity-framework

Using ASP.NET MVC and Entity Framework code-first.

I have a table with matches PK:

```
modelBuilder.Entity<Match>()
            .HasKey(e => new { e.Club_Id, e.Comp_Id, e.Match_Id });
```

A match needs 2 teams - `Home` and `Away`:

Team PK

```
modelBuilder.Entity<Team>()
            .HasKey(e => new { e.Team_Id, e.Club_Id });
```

```
[ForeignKey("Team_Id_Away, Club_Id")]
public virtual Team Team_Away { get; set; }

[Display(Name = "Away Team ID")]
[Required]
public string Team_Id_Away
{
    get { return GetValue<string>(); }
    set { SetValue(value); }
}
```

In my model repository, I have added the "Include".

```
var mylist = _context.Matches
                     .Include(pt => pt.Team_Away)
                     .Where(p => p.Club_Id == club_id && p.Comp_Id == comp_id);
return mylist.ToList();
```

```
public T GetValue<T>([CallerMemberName] string propertyName = null)
{
T result;
object val;
    if (_Values.TryGetValue(propertyName, out val))
    {
     result = (T)val;
    }
    else
    {
     result = default(T);
    }
    return result;
}

public void SetValue(object value, [CallerMemberName] string propertyName = null)
        {
            _Values[propertyName] = value;
            RaisePropertyChanged(propertyName);
        }
```

When in the view, the `Team_Away` table is always null as I am trying to get the team name from that table.

What am I missing ? (Same is true with the home team)

Comment: What is GetValue and SetValue? Use simple types. Auto-properties are quite sufficient. Also, avoid composite keys unless absolutely necessary. A PK should be unique and meaningless in that it's only purpose should be to identify the row, not describe the row if that descriptiveness itself is not unique. A Team should only need a TeamId while a match should only need a MatchId. It can have FKs to Teams, Clubs, etc. It just makes things a LOT simpler to work with, especially when learning something new.

Comment: @StevePy: I have added the code for the GetValue and Setvalue but it has no effect on the question asked.

Comment: The next detail is you mention in the title a null FK in the DB, yet your example is showing a Read /w eager load. If the FK is null then that points to an issue when you insert your data. If the DB your are inspecting shows data should be coming back but your entities aren't loading it, then your relationship mappings may have issues or possibly check your connection string at runtime to ensure it is pointing at the same Database instance you are verifying against.

Comment: Both teams are present in the DB as they are mandatory for a Match. When I do not use the Include, the Team_Id_Away is not null. The goal is to retrieve some info from the team table with the Team_Id_Away ID to be displayed in the match view.

Comment: ID in the team table is Team_id and the include is with Team_Away instead of Team...not sure it has to do anything with it.

Comment: If Team_Id is the PK in Teams then the `[ForeignKey]` attribute should just be Team_Id_Away, not both Team_Id_Away and Club_Id.

Comment: No the Full PK in Team is Team_Id +  Club_Id